# Resizing string arrays that may be too big

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc, realloc

Some background: I'm writing a C function that reads text from a file into a dynamically reallocated array. I start off with `BUF_SIZE` character, read until I've hit the limit, then reallocate. When I'm finished, I append `\0` at the end of the text (not the end of the array).

Is it considered better to leave the array too big (and lose a little bit of memory -- very little) or `realloc()` to the smaller size?

Comment: So are you doing exponential storage expansion?

Comment: To @H2CO3's first comment: I was just reallocating to the current size + `BUF_SIZE`.  To the second comment: Yes, that's what I'd guessed. Thanks!

Comment: Statistically, it's worth doubling the allocation size every time you hit the old limit. (May I write that as an answer?)

Comment: Feel free. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother `realloc()`ing to the final size. When the memory is not needed anymore, you will `free()` it anyway, and unless the string is huge, chances are that even if you `realloc()` it to a smaller size, the alignment requirements of `malloc()` will not change the space actually reserved, so you just make a superfluous call to a quite expensive function.

TL;DR: don't shrink the array!

And a piece of good advice: statistically, it's worth doubling the allocation size each time you hit the previous limit.